# Word2vec CBOW model implementations, deviations from the original algorithm

Tags: pytorch, word2vec

I am trying to implement CBOW model by pytorch. 
What I understood from the [explanation of word2vec](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf) is that word2vec has 2 layers (and therefore 2 matrices), the first matrix contains low dimensional word vectors, which is actually a lookup table and the vector representation of the word projected on the projection layer (no non-linearity, therefore not a hidden layer). The word vectors then multiplied by the 2nd matrix and the that goes to the output through a softmax function. After training, the first matrix can be used as a word embedding.

I see many implementation use 3 layers (1 embedding layer plus 2 more layers.), which is contradictory to my understanding above. Some example implementations [here](https://github.com/smafjal/continuous-bag-of-words-pytorch/blob/master/cbow_model_pytorch.py), [here](https://github.com/FraLotito/pytorch-continuous-bag-of-words/blob/master/cbow.py) and [here](https://srijithr.gitlab.io/post/word2vec/).
The following three lines of codes have commonly used as a model to implment 3 layer:

```
self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
self.linear1 = nn.Linear(context_size * embedding_dim, 128)
self.linear2 = nn.Linear(128, vocab_size)
```

My questions are, if my understanding is okay, then why they are using 3 layers? Are there any advantages?

One obvious disadvantage, I think is, it will be computationally expensive.

Word2vec resembles the idea of autoencoder (which also have two-layer), deviating from this proven idea might harm the embedding quality. Am I right?

Another important thing is that, according to the paper that I mentioned above, for multiple context words the average of the vectors will be projected on the protection layer. But instead of averaging, they are concatenating the vectors. Why is that? is there any advantages?

Also, they are using non-linearity at the hidden layer which I think will create a serious performance issue in training with a huge amount of data. Right?

Comment: Are these implementations perhaps modeling the traditional CBOW averaging as a propagation from that synthetic concatenated layer? In any case, the use of a fixed `128` value anywhere strikes me as fishy. They could be wrong! There's tons of erroneous examples/tutorials out there.

Comment: I was asking myself exactly the same, especially because in none of the implementations there is any explanations for this deviation from the original architecture. Still hoping that someone can shed some light on this.